# Users can add cells and edit their cells only.

Tags: excel

I want to create an multi user excel file that allows users to add cells and edit their own but not be able to edit or delete other users cells.

Comment: I think this is not the purpose excel is designed for. It's possible however with some complex VBA macro. Would it be possible to change to e.g. MS Access or a Sharepoint list (I think your file is already stored on a network drive so this would be the optimal solution)?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a password-base unlocking of specific cells. See below the sequence of steps, extracted from

http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-enable-excel-cell-range-editing-by-certain-.html

A custom implemented method is drafted here

http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/549315-protect-cells-specific-users.html

---

**Password-based protection**

1. Click the Allow Users to Edit Ranges command button on the Ribbon’s Review tab or press Alt+RU.
2. Click the New button.
3. If you wish, type a name for the range in the Title text box; otherwise, Excel assigns a name such as Range1, Range2, and so on.
4. Click the Refers to Cells text box and then type in the address of the cell range (without removing the = sign) or select the range or ranges in the worksheet.
5. Type in the password for accessing the range in the Range Password dialog box.
6. Click the Permissions button in the Range Password dialog box.
7. Click the Add button in the Permissions dialog box.
8. Click the name of the user in the Enter the Object Names to Select list box at the bottom of the Select Users or Groups dialog box. To select multiple users from this list, hold down the Ctrl key as you click each username.
9. Click OK in the Select Users or Groups dialog box.
10. Click the name of the first user who must know the password and then select the Deny check box in the Permissions For list box.
11. Repeat Step 10 for each user who must know the password and then click OK in the Permissions dialog box.
12. Click the Yes button in the Security alert dialog box.
13. Click OK in the New Range dialog box.
14. Type the range password in the Reenter Password to Proceed text box and then click the OK button.
15. (Optional) Select the Paste Permissions Information Into a New Workbook check box if you want to create a new workbook that contains all the permissions information.
16. Click the Protect Sheet button to protect the worksheet; otherwise, click the OK button to close the Allow Users to Edit Ranges dialog box.